# How do I apply a filter to every request, using Dart and the route package?

Tags: dart, dart-io

I am writing server-side Dart, and I'm using the http_server and route packages. I'd like to run a filter for every single request.

In this particular case, I want to add CORS headers.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
  new Router(server)
    ..serve('/register', method: 'POST')
      .transform(new HttpBodyHandler()).listen(registerPlayer)
    ..serve('/matches', method: 'GET')
      .transform(new HttpBodyHandler()).listen(listMatches)
    ..serve('/matches', method: 'POST')
      .transform(new HttpBodyHandler()).listen(createMatch)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `filter` with a `RegExp` to match every request.

```
  new Router(server)
    ..filter(new RegExp(r'^.*$'), addCorsHeaders)
    ..serve('/register', method: 'POST')
      .transform(new HttpBodyHandler()).listen(registerPlayer)
    ..... more handlers
```

The filter must be a `Future<bool> filter(HttpRequest req)`:

```
Future<bool> addCorsHeaders(HttpRequest req) {
  log.fine('Adding CORS headers');
  req.response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  return new Future.sync(() => true);
}
```

Comment: For lazy guys: `new Future.sync(() => true);` can be replaced by `new Future.value(true);`.